# Using ios_webkit_debug_proxy on linux

Tags: javascript, iphone, linux, google-chrome, remote-debugging

I am trying to use the description from https://github.com/google/ios-webkit-debug-proxy to debug my website on iPhone (Running iOS 7.1.2).

I compiled ios_webkit_debug_proxy, and is running it with
ios_webkit_debug_proxy -d

I then start google-chrome and point it to `localhost:9222/` which shows my iPhone, and the website it is currently visiting. I then copy/paste the link address`(chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/devtools.html?host=localhost:9222&page=1)` into a new chrome tab, and then I get a debug window which shows

```
Elements,Network,Sources,Timeline,Profiles,Resources,Audits,Console.
```

But none of theese buttons shows any real content. There is no dom. No javascript. No output in the console view. No activity in the network. Its like debugging a empty view.

My ios_webkit_debug_proxy -d console, shows a new message, each time my iPhone
visits a new website. But it shows no other activity. THe messages start with something like

```
ss.remove_fd(7)
ss.recv fd=13 len=0
ss.remove_fd(13)
ss.recv fd=12 len=221
wi.recv[221]:
```

And they do just as far as I can see, contain the website url, but not any real content from the website.

The console I started chrome from, shows the message:

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'frame' of undefined", source: chrome-devtools:/
```

I am using Fedora 20.

Does anyone have any clue why this does not work ?
Thanks

Comment: Chrome 38? Chrome 37? Should work with Chrome 37

Comment: I am using Chmore version 38.0.2125.122 (64-bit). Are you saying it will work if I downgrade to Chrome 37?

Comment: Yeah, why dont you try it, if it does then we try and can nail the problem with the new build

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear to me if you switch the browser to `localhost:9222/` **after** you get a pair of lines like:

```
Listing devices on :9221
Connected :9222 to Will's iPhone (8a48ac86edd4f299xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)
```

if you don't see the second line, then it means that probably you have issues with `usbmuxd` or `libimobiledevice`.

I've had some issues myself with the proxy, but then i was able to use it with satisfaction. In my experience, there are few things that make the life easier:

1) Run the usbmuxd as root  and possibly with options -fv so that it doesn't detach from the tty and you see what happens. In my Debian installation it is run wit a system user in background;

2) In order to avoid the crash of the proxy when an unhandled exception happens don't use the debugger release of your chrome/chromium but instead use a pretty older one https://chrome-devtools-frontend.appspot.com/static/18.0.1025.99/devtools.html (see https://github.com/google/ios-webkit-debug-proxy/issues/63)